# Modifying Github Python script to allow other mime-types

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda

I was able to get the below script to work, pulling files from an S3 bucket into Google Drive.

The script was clearly designed to only do Spreadsheets, but I'm hoping to use it for multiple file types like jpg, jpeg, mp3 etc

https://github.com/dspenard/google-drive-with-aws

The only place I see it mentioning spreadsheet mime-type is in the last line, I tried changing it there to a couple different mime-types but it errors out.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I was able to get this to work by using the mimetypes module

Import mimetypes

## Final codeblock reads

```
for file_name in event['fileList']:
    download_path = '/tmp/{}'.format(file_name)
    s3_client.download_file(bucket, file_name, download_path)
    mime_type = mimetypes.read_mime_types(file_name)
    upload_file(service, download_path, file_name, file_name, folder_id, mime_type)
```